# can anyone simplify this code for me in c?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, char, scanf

The sum of all odd digits of n.(eg. n is 32677, the sum would be 3+7+7=17)

Here is the code.
For this question, any of loop or function is acceptable, but not longer than this answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char n[20];
  int m=0,i;
  printf("Enter integers for the variable n: ");
  for (i=0;i<20;i++)
  {
    scanf("%c",&n[i]);
    if(n[i]=='\n')
    {
      break;
    }
  }
  for (i=0;i<20;i++)// this is the part I would like to simplified
  {
    if (n[i]%2!=0)
    {
      if(n[i]==49)
      m++;
      if(n[i]==51)
      m+=3;
      if(n[i]==53)
      m+=5;
      if(n[i]==55)
      m+=7;
      else if(n[i]==57)
      m+=9;
    }
  }
  printf("The sum of odd digits of n is %d.",m);
}
```

Comment: could you explain the usage of 49,51,53,55,57 ?

Comment: @daShier has a nice simplification in his answer, but you could add his code into the loop where you read the numbers from the user to make it even more simple.

Comment: @mangusta 48-57 are the ascii codes for numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some tools/ideas you can use:

- In ctype.h is a function `isdigit()` which tells you whether or not a character represents a digit.
- Assuming the characters for the digits 0..9 are in sequence, the value represented by a character digit `c` is `c-'0'`

Answer (score 0):

Here you are

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    enum { N = 20 };
    char value[N];

    printf( "Enter an unsigned integer: " );

    size_t n = 0;

    for ( char digit; n < N && scanf( "%c", &digit ) == 1 && digit != '\n'; ++n ) 
    {
        value[n] = digit;
    }

    unsigned int sum = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( value[i] % 2 != 0 ) sum += value[i] - '0';
    }

    printf( "The sum of odd digits of the value is %u.\n", sum );
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter an unsigned integer: 0123456789
The sum of odd digits of the value is 25
```

Or you can add a check that an entered character is a digit. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( void )
{
    enum { N = 20 };
    char value[N];

    printf( "Enter an unsigned integer: " );

    size_t n = 0;

    for ( char digit; 
          n < N && scanf( "%c", &digit ) == 1 && isdigit( ( unsigned char )digit );
          ++n )
    {
        value[n] = digit;
    }

    unsigned int sum = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( value[i] % 2 != 0 ) sum += value[i] - '0';
    }

    printf( "The sum of odd digits of the value is %u\n", sum );
}
```

As for your code then in this loop

```
  for (i=0;i<20;i++)
  {
    scanf("%c",&n[i]);
    if(n[i]=='\n')
    {
      break;
    }
  }
```

you have to count how many digits were entered. And the new line character shall not be stored in the array. Otherwise this loop

```
  for (i=0;i<20;i++)
```

can result in undefined behavior.

And you should not use magic numbers like for example `49`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation, it helps a lot.